# How do I mix all this logic with javascript Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird in Node, and I'm still pretty new to using Promises, especially when things start getting beyond the basics.

Here's a function I need to construct using Promises, and I'm struggling to figure out the best way to set it up.  At a high level, this function will take a model object, and return it, converting any query properties to their result sets.  For example, a property can have a value of "query(top5Products)", and we'll need to lookup that named query and replace the value with the results of that query.  Properties can also be an actual string-based query (using RQL, e.g. "eq(contentType,products)&&limit(5,0)")  This converted model object will then be used to bind against a template.

Here's my pseudo-coded function, currently synchronous except for the calls to existing promise-returning services...

```
function resolveQueryPropertiesOnModel(model) {
    for (let property in model) {
        if (model.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            let queryName = this.getNameOfNamedQuery(model[property]); // will return undefined if the property is not a named query
            if (queryName) {
                // this property is a named query, so get it from the database
                this.getByName(queryName)
                    .then((queryObject) => {
                        // if queryObject has a results propery, that's the cached resultset - use it
                        if (queryObject && queryObject.results) {
                            model[property] = queryObject.results;
                        }
                        else {
                            // need to resolve the query to get the results                            
                            this.resolve(queryObject.query)
                                .then((queryResults) => {
                                    model[property] = queryResults;
                                });
                        }

                    };
            }
            else if (this.isQuery(model[property]) { // check to see if this property is an actual query
                // resolve the query to get the results
                this.resolve(model[property])
                    .then((queryResults) => {
                        model[property] = queryResults;
                    });                    
            }
        }
    }
    // return some sort of promise that will eventually become the converted model,
    // with all query properties converted to their resultsets
    return ???;
}
```

I'm still very rusty when it comes to taking loops with logic and some pre-existing promises and mashing them all together.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it.

- a q.all() will be resolved if all of the promises are resolved. each promise is one property in the model that is processed.
- for each property (I'd use a library like lodash and _.reduce, but you can use the hasOwnProperty if you like). anyway, foreach property, resolveModelProperty function returns a promise that decides the fate of the property, if there is a query name, get it, if not and there is a query, resolve it, if not, don't change the property.
- to helper functions, resolveByName and resolveQuery will handle the case of cached and uncached queries.

```js
function resolveQueryPropertiesOnModel(model) {
   const promises = [],
        resolveQuery = toBeResolved => this.resolve(toBeResolved),
        resolveByName = queryName => this.getByName(queryName)
    .then(queryObject => queryObject && queryObject.results 
                   ? queryObject.results : resolveQuery(queryObject.query)),
        resolveModelProperty = (modelProperty) => {
         const queryName = this.getNameOfNamedQuery(modelProperty);
         return queryName ? resolveByName(queryName) : 
                  this.isQuery(modelProperty) ? resolveQuery(modelProperty):
                          modelProperty;
        };

 for(let property in model)
  if( model.hasOwnProperty(property)
   promises.push(resolveModelProperty(model[property])
                          .then(result=> model[property]=result));
 return q.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `q.all()` when the question is explicitly tagged with Bluebird which uses `Promise.all()`?

Comment: the point was to show how the logic can be done in promises. the name of global variable for promise library may vary, the answer still holds. angularjs uses $q.

Comment: Just not sure why you'd use q syntax when the question explicitly asks for Bluebird.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for an alternative solution to the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of your code using Bluebird that makes these structural changes:

1. Runs the outer `for` loop and collects any promises that were started
2. Returns nested promises to chain them so they are linked and so the top level promise will indicate when everything is done in that chain
3. Collects any new promises into the `promises` array
4. Uses `Promise.all(promises)` to track when all the async promise operations are done and returns that.
5. It appears your result is the side effect of modifying the `models` object so no explicit values are returned through the promises.  You can use the returned promise to know when all the async operations are done and you can then examine the `model` object for results.

Code:

```
function resolveQueryPropertiesOnModel(model) {
    const promises = [];
    for (let property in model) {
        let p;
        if (model.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            let queryName = this.getNameOfNamedQuery(model[property]); // will return undefined if the property is not a named query
            if (queryName) {
                // this property is a named query, so get it from the database
                p = this.getByName(queryName).then((queryObject) => {
                    // if queryObject has a results propery, that's the cached resultset - use it
                    if (queryObject && queryObject.results) {
                        model[property] = queryObject.results;
                    } else {
                        // need to resolve the query to get the results                            
                        return this.resolve(queryObject.query).then((queryResults) => {
                            model[property] = queryResults;
                        });
                    }
                };
            } else if (this.isQuery(model[property]) { // check to see if this property is an actual query
                // resolve the query to get the results
                p = this.resolve(model[property]).then((queryResults) => {
                    model[property] = queryResults;
                });                    
            }
        }
        // if we started a new promise, then push it into the array
        if (p) {
            promises.push(p);
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: using var is considered bad practice. in this code, let is also not required for declaration of promises. const is a better choice, since promises variable doesn't get re-assigned.

Comment: Good, solid answer.  Thanks for helping me understand that the return just needs to make sure all the internal promises are finished.  I'm going with the other answer simply because it gives another perspective on how to solve the logic, but you've got an upvote.